# Foxpro Website Front End-Can't read From Drop Down List

Tags: php, html, foxpro

Good morning, 
 I am building a website to act as a Foxpro front end. It's working great except for my one drop down box that has to read a list of names from another Foxpro table. The drop down works fine, but whenever I submit the form the page just resets.

Here's my code.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<form action= "test.php" method="post"?
<label>Provider:
<select name="lstProvider" id="1stProvider">
<?php
require_once('odbc.php');//this file just handles the connection
$strsql= 'SELECT Distinct id,name FROM provider.dbf';
$query = odbc_exec($odbc, $strsql) or die (odbc_errormsg());
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query))

{
echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: You have two `<form>` tags at the top - should they both be there?

Comment: DOH! Thank you andrewsi XD That was the problem.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two `<form>` tags at the top of the page.

Also, you have my sympathy for having to work with FoxPro.